# Timber Twig - Split Category Posts if Date/Time is Past/Present/Future

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, twig, timber

I am using ACF to link to Zoom Webinars. Ive used ACF to add both Start and End Date/Times.
I have a standard condition that checks for Past/Present/Future on the these fields

```
{% if w_start %}
    {% if current >= w_start and current <= w_end %}
        {#% present %#}
    {% elseif current > w_end %}
        {#% past %#}
    {% else %}
        {#% future %#}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

How do I split an archive post list into three separate headings defined by a past/present/future condition.

**Current Webinars**

---

**Upcoming Webinars**

---

**Past Webinars**

---

I am presently not passing other arguments to this page.

```
$context['post'] = Timber::get_posts();
return Timber::render('webinar-archive.twig', $context, false);
```

-

```
{% for webinar in post %}
    {#% Do Something %#}
{% endfor %}
```

Do I create 3 separate for loops? Do I sort based on the if condition?

Any help or direction would be great here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you loop over your posts in the PHP template so that they're separated within the context. The [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function can help:

```php
$context['posts_by_time'] = array_reduce(Timber::get_posts(), function($byTime, $post) {
  $start = strtotime($post->w_start);
  $end   = strtotime($post->w_end);

  if (time() > $start && time() < $end) {
    $section = 'current';
  } elseif (time() > $end) {
    $section = 'past';
  } else {
    $section = 'future';
  }

  // add this post to the correct section
  $byTime[$section][] = $post;

  return $byTime;
}, [
  'past'    => [],
  'current' => [],
  'future'  => [],
]);
```

Then in your view code you have a nice simple array of sections to work with:

```
<h2>Current Webinars</h2>
{% for webinar in posts_by_time.current %}
  {# render each current post #}
{% endfor %}

{# and so on for future & past #}
```

**NOTE:** I didn't test this code but that's the general idea.